# Different format for header image and text

Tags: visual-foxpro, word-automation

I need a company logo and some text on the header of word document,
While the logo is on the left side, I need the text to align centre and with 25% shading.

If without the inline logo, the text is center with shading, but with the inline image all text format are gone.
Should I separate image and text into 2 paragraph and apply format, how ?

Comment: I'd use a two-celled table to do this.

Comment: yes, after wasting lot of hours, I follow your way to do it.